# How to remove the data fetch in this Entity Framework Update?

Tags: entity-framework

Can I restructure this query so I don't have to fetch from the database? I have tried various techniques, but none of them work.

```
    public void Update(CartEntryViewModel entry)
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            User user = Auth.GetUser(context);
            CartEntry model = context.CartEntries.Find(entry.Id);

            // Change the item and update quantity
            model.Item = context.Items.Find(entry.Item.Id);
            model.Quantity = entry.Quantity;
            context.Entries(model).EntityState = EntityState.Modified;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Attach() method takes the model you already have and attaches it to the context as if it were just read from the DB.  You just have to change the state so the context knows to update the corresponding row in the DB when SaveChanges() is called.

```
public void Update(CartEntryViewModel entry)
{
    CartEntry model = new CartEntry
    {
        model.Id = entry.Id,
        model.Item = entry.Item,
        model.Quantity = entry.Quantity,
        // Set other properties.     
    };

    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())   
    {
        context.CartEntries.Attach(model);
        context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, `entry` is not an object that is ever saved to the db.

Comment: Does the view model contain all of the necessary information to reverse engineer the model?  That's really the only way you'll be able to avoid hitting the database.  See my updates to the code snippet.

Comment: `entry.Item` does not contain all the information either. However, the item doesn't change.